# Correct way to React axios post with UUID and nested object in JSON payload?

Tags: reactjs, axios

My server-side application accepts an int, does some simple math, and returns an int as Content-Type application/json. The api has been tested with Postman and works correctly.

I'm looking for the proper way to handle an Axios POST with a JSON payload that includes a UUID with an object nested below it. As suggested, I added `['']` around the UUID to play nicely with React. If I click 'Post' without entering a value my server returns an int for 'current_value'. If I enter a number in the field 'current_value' returns a string e.g., 4 + 2 = `"42"`.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class Post extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      current_value: 0
    };

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ current_value: event.target.value });
    console.log(event.target.value);
  };

  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    axios.post('http://my.server.url', {
      foo: 'bar',
      ['e0ea641b-3de4-4a76-857d-11da9352698a']: { current_value: this.state.current_value }
    })
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({ current_value: response.data.current_value });
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
      });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label>Input Number:
            <input type="number" name="current_value" onChange={this.handleChange} />
          </label>
          <button type="submit">Post</button>
        </form>
        <div>
            Output Number: { this.state.current_value }
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Post;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to escape your uuid like below, it should work:

```
{
    foo: 'bar',
    ['e0ea641b-3de4-4a76-857d-11da9352698a']:{ current_value: this.state.current_value }
}
```

Comment: No problem @DanielBell, give it a try and let us know if it works by accepting and upvoting the answer! thanks

Comment: Hi Guilherme, thanks for the response. That partially worked, in that it does compile and the UUID gets sent upstream as a string. However, it seems that my `.then` statement turns 'current_value' into a string. If I wrap that part of the payload `{ current_value: JSON.parse(this.state.current_value) }` it solves most of the problem, however if I then click 'Submit' without entering a number I get a Javascript error.

Comment: that is strange, as you defined the default this.state.current_value as 0 in the constructor, it should work as JSON.parse(0) equals 0... maybe your onChange handler is being triggered even before the user types the number? Try to add a console log within handleChange to check that!

Comment: Everything works great except: Reload -> click 'submit' (state is 0) it works. Click 'submit' again (without entering a number) I get `react-dom.development.js:244 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0` -- Actually, I get that error twice.

Comment: I see... so it seems like the wrong value is being set in state in the then block. Have you tried logging response.data.current_value to see what you get? Also, where are you using JSON.parser(), in your post payload or in your then response?

Comment: I think you need to treat current_value as a string in the whole flow, as that is the type you'll get from your input event and also the type you get from your response.data.current_value, and I'm not sure you need JSON.parser() at all, I think it is messing with your data somewhere in the flow

Comment: Post payload. Here's my .then block: `.then(response => {
        this.setState({ current_value: response.data.current_value });
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
      });` When it doesn't crash, that console.log line shows what I'd expect.

Comment: I would say: either don't use JSON.parse/JSON.stringify() at all, or use JSON.stringify() before setting the state in the then block, like: `.then(response => { this.setState({ current_value: JSON.stringify(response.data).current_value }); console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data)); });`

Comment: With this as my payload `['e0ea641b-3de4-4a76-857d-11da9352698a']: { current_value: this.state.current_value }` and no JSON.parse() anywhere then: Reload -> click 'submit' and 'current_value' returns a number. Click again and 'current_value' is null. If I then enter a number and click 'submit' 'current_value' becomes a string e.g., 4 + 2 = 42.

Comment: I'm not sure how your server side code works, does it return the response header application/json? do you have an example somewhere that I could test? Or maybe update your code in the question with the better version, it is getting difficult for me to understand the whole picture. As the UUID issue was solved maybe this even deserve a new question! thanks

Comment: I revised my question as suggested, and yes the UUID question was answered, I appreciate your help. The app is still broken though. I'm still getting javascript errors or 'current_value' coming back as a string.

Comment: nice, that's better, could you also post a sample of your server response?

Comment: also, could you at least upvote my answer, as it solved your original problem?

Comment: Here are my reponses from the server. I have no JSON.stringify() or JSON.parse() statements.    Reload, click 'Post' --> `{"e0ea641b-3de4-4a76-857d-11da9352698a":{"current_value":2}}`  This is correct; 0 + 2 = 2.  Click 'Post' again without reloading --> `{"e0ea641b-3de4-4a76-857d-11da9352698a":{"current_value":null}}`  If at any time I actually enter a number (e.g., 4) -->  `{"e0ea641b-3de4-4a76-857d-11da9352698a":{"current_value":"42"}}`

Comment: I upvoted your answer, but since I'm such a noob it doesn't seem to count. It counts with me though!

Answer (score 1):

With a nod to help from @GuilhermeLemmi, I've landed on the answer that addresses both my initial issue and the problem of handling the response where the item in question contains a minus sign `-`. Wrapping my UUID in `[]` in the `data` object wasn't necessary, but I did need to wrap it in single quotes. On the return side I *did* need to wrap the response in `['']` but leave it as an object, *don't* `JSON.stringify()` it. Now everything flows nice and smooth.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class Post extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      current_value: 0
    };

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ current_value: JSON.parse(event.target.value)});
    console.log(event.target.value);
  };

  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const data = {
      foo: 'bar',
      'e0ea641b-3de4-4a76-857d-11da9352698a': {
    current_value: this.state.current_value
      }
    };

    console.log(data);

    axios.post('http://my.server.url', data)
      .then(response => {
        const obj = response.data;
        this.setState({ current_value: obj['e0ea641b-3de4-4a76-857d-11da9352698a'].current_value });
        console.log(obj['e0ea641b-3de4-4a76-857d-11da9352698a'].current_value);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label>Input Number:
            <input type="number" name="current_value" onChange={this.handleChange} />
          </label>
          <button type="submit">Post</button>
        </form>
        <div>
            Output Number: { this.state.current_value }
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Post;
```